# opencv saved video very faster plaing

Tags: python, opencv

I capture video from my camera, but when i save this i received very fast video. Can i capture video with original frame rate?

```
import cv2
import time

# exit(1)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.0.66/live1.sdp")
ps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)  # float
# Get current height of frame
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
FILE_OUTPUT = 'out.avi'
FPS = 20.0
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, FPS)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(FILE_OUTPUT, fourcc, FPS, (int(width), int(height)))

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:

        # Write the frame into the file 'output.avi'
        out.write(frame)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        #  cv2.waitKey(100)
        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Break the loop
    else:
        break

    # When everything done, release the video capture and video write objects
cap.release()
out.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

P.S i use opencv 4 and python3.  I try change waitKey option but it had no effect

Comment: What's the value of `ps`. I mean what's frame rate of the ip camera?

Comment: PS is 75, but I don't understand why.camera max fps is 30

Comment: Are you able to set the frame rate in the rtsp string? If not, I recommend measuring the frame rate in your `while True` loop and matching that in your `out` variable.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer. i will try